# Maximize the line integral in a region

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

A vector field $\vec F$ is defined on the disk $D$ of radius $5$

$$\vec F=\big[-y^3+y\sin(xy)\big]\hat{x}+\big[4x(1-y^2)+x\sin(xy)\big]\hat{y}$$

Consider the line integral

$$ \int_C  \vec F\,\mathrm{d}r  $$

where $C$ is some closed curve contained in $D$. For which $C$ is this integral the largest?

We used Green's Theorem and found that $-2≤y≤2$, so $C$ is the boundary of the region bounded by $y=2$, $y=-2$ $\cup$ two circular arcs, and this maximizes the line integral. I don't see it.

Comment: What do you mean with $x\in D$? $x$ is a one dimensional variable and $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$..

Comment: We're doing the double integral $$\int  \int 4-y^2 dydx$$

Comment: Have you been given any orientation of the curve? Clockwise or counterclockwise? Also when you say _we used Green's Theorem_, are you referring to a solution that you are going through and trying to understand?

Comment: The solution wasn't written in detail it was stated. I tried to edit my meaning for what the region looks like because I realized from @Gabrielek that $x\in D$ didn't make sense in this context. And yes we are assuming the curve C is positively oriented, smooth, and doesn't cross itself

Comment: What is the orientation of the curve?

Comment: But yes I'm trying to understand how this even works, or what the actual solution is. If D is a disk I'm not even understanding how the boundary of this region is contained in D .. It's not, but the book purportedly defines the disk to be closed (it doesn't)

Comment: It is positive, we can assume. The exercise doesn't actually indicate, but it says "Hint: assume C is positively oriented and doesn't cross itself, smooth"

Comment: That is not correct. The line integral is largest for a clockwise oriented curve.

Comment: So maybe this is why I'm having so much trouble with this because the book has a mistake. It says counterclockwise.

Comment: Is the answer the boundary of the disk D oriented clockwise?

Comment: I don't have solutions for the book, and it was an even exercise. It's from McCallum multivariable calculus 7th ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The question should have provided with the orientation*. In fact, the line integral is largest for a clockwise oriented curve.

If $\vec F = (P, Q)$. For a clockwise oriented curve and given vector field, $P_y - Q_x = y^2-4$. We note that $(y^2-4)$ is negative for $|y| \lt 2$ and positive for $ |y| \gt 2$. I will use it later in the answer.

If we take a closed curve which is boundary of the disk, it is easy to see that,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^5 r (r^2\sin^2\theta - 4) \ dr \ d\theta = \frac{225\pi}{4} \approx 176.715$

[Now we could find a piece-wise smooth simple closed curve oriented clockwise which avoids most of the region between $-2 \leq y \leq 2$ and that would make the integral even larger.]

If we put a restriction that it is a counterclockwise oriented closed curve as the book says in the hint, the integral becomes

$\displaystyle \int_C \vec F \cdot d\vec r = \iint_R (4-y^2) \ dA$

The below diagram depicts the closed curve that would maximize the line integral.

[image]

We know that $(4-y^2)$ is negative for $|y| \gt 2$. The closed curve depicted in the diagram avoids any point where $|y| \gt 2$ but also exploits max range of $-5 \leq x \leq 5$.

You can do the integral in couple different ways. I will do it over the rectangle in the first quadrant and then over region between line segment $AB$ and arc $AB$ above x-axis and then multiply the integral by $4$ due to symmetry.

$\displaystyle 4 \int_0^{\sqrt {21}} \int_0^2 (4 - y^2) \ dy \ dx + 4 \int_{\sqrt{21}}^5 \int_0^{\sqrt{25-x^2}} (4 - y^2) \ dy \ dx \approx 104.9293$

Comment: Thanks for pulling it together in a clean way. I got clockwise curve too but the book stated counterclockwise so I omitted that first attempt, the hint in the book says "Assume C is a smooth curve oriented counterclockwise that doesn't cross itself". I suppose you could argue that the book wants us to find -225pi/4 using a counterclockwise curve and then know to change the orientation, but the way it is worded made me think I was missing some counterclockwise oriented curve that made the integral larger. This is junior level multivariable calculus, and none of the students got it, either

Comment: Yes but once we put the restriction of counterclockwise, it becomes a more interesting problem because the closed curve that maximizes the line integral is combination of circular arcs and straight lines.